# Reduce duplicate records like a DISTINCT , result set must be in correct order

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The original data set looks like this (but it is a lot longer)

| Id | Bcolumn |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 5 |
| 124 | 5 |
| 125 | 6 |
| 126 | 7 |
| 127 | 7 |
| 128 | 8 |
| 129 | 8 |
| 130 | 8 |
| 131 | 8 |
| 132 | 5 |
| 133 | 5 |

I need to make something like a DISTINCT on this set, on Bcolumn, but the result set's order has to be the same order as the default set. AND the 5's have to be in the beginning of the set and the end of the set too. So basically the result would look like this.

| Id | Bcolumn |
| --- | --- |
| 124 | 5 |
| 125 | 6 |
| 126 | 7 |
| 130 | 8 |
| 133 | 5 |

The Id column's values are not important in my case, so the result's first set is 124/5 but 123/5 would also work for me. I just added the ID column because I was thinking to use the Id column somehow in a fancy SELECT.

Originally I was thinking about using DISTINCT, but I realized that the result set would not include both records with 5 on the Bcolumn.

So currently my best bet would be something like a fetch-next/cursor, creating a temporary table, but that would be big and ugly, I was hoping that this can be done in nicer way.

Note - I am using MS SQL 2008, but I can upgrade the database if needed.

Comment: *but I can upgrade the database if needed* - then you should upgrade!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your data it *appears* you might need a solution to identify sequential groups to include in your aggregation.

Does the following provide a usable solution?

```
with g as (
select *,  row_number() over(partition by b order by id) r, row_number() over(order by id) rn
from t
)
select max(id) Id, b
from g
group by b, rn-r
order by Id;
```

[See example DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=735ab1cdf79cf7a7133f4dce82313087)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the following table...

```
SELECT
    Id,
    Bcolumn
INTO
    #T
FROM
    (VALUES 
        (123, 5),
        (124, 5),
        (125, 6),
        (126, 7),
        (127, 7),
        (128, 8),
        (129, 8),
        (130, 8),
        (131, 8),
        (132, 5),
        (133, 5)
    ) T(Id, Bcolumn);
```

...the following query...

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    #T T_CURRENT
WHERE
    Bcolumn NOT IN (
        SELECT TOP 1
            Bcolumn
        FROM
            #T T_NEXT
        WHERE
            T_CURRENT.Id < T_NEXT.Id
        ORDER BY
            T_NEXT.Id
    )
ORDER BY
    Id;
```

...gives the following result:

| Id | Bcolumn |
| --- | --- |
| 124 | 5 |
| 125 | 6 |
| 127 | 7 |
| 131 | 8 |
| 133 | 5 |

The `Id`s are not exactly the same as in your example, but I think you were aiming at something like this.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little hard to tell exactly what you want, but this produces the results you specify:

```
select bcolumn, min(id)
from t
group by bcolumn
union all
select 5, max(id)
from t
where bcolumn = 5;
```